# Website A 'redirect' to subdomain of website B, with content of website A

Tags: iis, redirect, dns, web

There has been a question made towards me recently to do the following:
We have a website with Drupal running in IIS.
On that site is an URL Redirect to a website hosted externally, obviously with a name completely irrelevant to the name of our company.
The question now is the following;

1. They want to change to URL to a subdomain of our website. Example: from "www.external-site.com" to "www.sub.internal.com" (while still showing content of the external website)
2. They want the current page of that website to be reflected in the URL bar. So it wouldn't say "www.sub.internal.com", but it would say "www.sub.internal.com/solutions/page1.html" (instead of "www.external-site.com/solutions/page1.html")

It's possible that I forgot another 'condition' but have mentioned before this.
So, if someone visits through our URL Redirect to External-website, it needs to show our subdomain instead of their domain in the URL, AND it needs to show the current page when people start browsing while still using our subdomain in the URL.

Now, I checked the external-website, and it seems that most of the links available are relative links (if this would be any useful information).

Currently, the external website is hosted externally, and will remain to be so for next few years. (I believe we bought the company)

I have been asking around and looking up, and the best possible thing seems to use domain forwarding, but even then it still doesn't seem to comply with the entirety that they asked of me.

I am but a 'simple' .NET programmer, held responsible to do support for anything involving the websites, and I can't say I have extended knowledge about infrastructure. (But I can ask people to do this for me)

Is there anything that could solve this?
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

IIS's URL rewite and Application Request Routing (ARR) combo can help you what you want to achive. Here are few links which may guide you to configure ARR. Please note that these links dont exibit exact solution to your problem however you can take clue from it and fabricate your solution accordingly.

1. http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing
2. http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-rule-template

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you'll want to use a full-page iframe: do not redirect but show a page with an "inner page" instead: that inner page is the external web site. That way, users do not see the external site in their URL bar.

http://webdesign.about.com/od/iframes/a/aaiframe.htm

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the equivalent of Apache Virtual Host with Reverse Proxy on IIS.

See this answers:

https://serverfault.com/a/271030
and
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10003306/2131693